# Showing result of a field value formula in view in LOTUS notes

Tags: datetime, lotus-notes

I have a formula based on a field value called `TTArs` (it is a computed date/time field showing only the time, eg: 15:31, which is calculated based on other two editable date/time fields. In other words, it is the difference between the other 2 date/time fields).

The formula is something like this:

```
@Hour(TTArs)*60+@Minute(TTArs)
```

I want to calculate all the minutes in that field time displayed on that field.

The result it should be a number (I guess). I want to display it on a column in a view, but it is showing an error on that column in view:

> Incorrect Data type for operator or @Function Time/Date expected.

I created a hidden field on the form where I want to store the number of minutes from the difference between the 2 date/time fields, it is computed, its name is "Untitled".

Here's the code

```
@If(text_orarezrs=null | text_oratrimrs=null; @Return(""); "");
seconds := text_orarezrs-text_oratrimrs;
minutes := @Integer(seconds/60);
output := @Text(minutes);
@SetField("Untitled";output)
```

`text_orarezrs` and `text_oratrimrs` are the 2 date/time fields (they are not text fields). But it doesn't show anything on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Florin!
I presume that the field you want to use on the view is the one we computed in your last question? If so, please stop and think - in that formula, you created a **text** value, even though it is displaying a time ("hh:mm").  So you now have two options if you want to display that in a view as a number of minutes.

1. Create a formula to take the text to the left of the ":", convert it to a number, multiply it by 60, then take the text to the right of the ":", convert it to a number and add it to the first number
2. Create a formula to calculate the number of minutes from the two original date fields (which I presume have been saved in the form)

Personally, I would do the second one of these.  All you need is to check that neither field is null, then subtract one from the other, then divide by 60 (you remember that date/time - date/time always gives the answer in seconds, of course).

Happy coding,
Phil

Comment: Yes, Phil it is the field from the last question. But I replied you there that isn't working well, it shows something like: 06:79.

Comment: I just change the 3rd field from Editable from Computed, I put the code part in its default value, and now it didn't show anything at all

Comment: From  your code at the last question, if the minutes are, let say, 86, they are showing 86. ( but the minutes must be <= 59 )